# Strings converting oddly when inserted into database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I'm a student working on my first Android Studio project. My attempts to search for this problem have led to a lot of date formatting results which I'm reasonably sure is not the problem.

I create an object with an int and three `String` parameters. Two of the strings are converted from `Date` object. It all seems to be going well until I call the DAO to insert it into the database. It does insert, but the two converted-date strings are no longer strings.  Can someone tell me why this is happening and how I can make it stop?  My best guesses at the needed code below:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {

    mTermDao.deleteAllTerms();

    Calendar calobj = Calendar.getInstance();
    calobj.add(Calendar.MONTH, -3);
    calobj.add(Calendar.DATE, -3);
    Date notToday = calobj.getTime();
    calobj.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
    Date next = calobj.getTime();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
    String strDateOne = dateFormat.format(notToday);
    String strDateTwo = dateFormat.format(next);
    String termTitle = "Term 1";

    TermEntity termEntity= new TermEntity(1,termTitle, strDateOne, strDateTwo);
    mTermDao.insert(termEntity);

    return null;
}
```

And the Dao

```java
@Dao
public interface TermDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(TermEntity termEntity);
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class TermViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private ScheduleRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<TermEntity>> mAllTerms;
    public TermViewModel(Application application){
        super(application);
        mRepository=new ScheduleRepository(application);
        mAllTerms =mRepository.getAllTerms();
    }
    public LiveData<List<TermEntity>> getAllTerms(){
        return mAllTerms;
    }
    public void insert(TermEntity termEntity){
        mRepository.insert(termEntity);
    }
    public void delete(TermEntity termEntity){
        mRepository.delete(termEntity);
    }
    public int lastID(){
        return mAllTerms.getValue().size();
    }
}
```

The TermEntity

```
@Entity(tableName="term_table")
public class TermEntity {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int termId;
    private String termTitle;
    private String termStart;
    private String termEnd;

    public TermEntity(int termId, String termTitle, String termStart, String termEnd) {
        this.termId = termId;
        this.termTitle = termTitle;
        this.termStart = termStart;
        this.termEnd = termEnd;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TermEntity{" +
                "termId=" + termId +
                ", termTitle='" + termTitle + '\'' +
                ", termStart=" + termStart +
                ", termEnd=" + termEnd +
                '}';
    }

    public int getTermId() {
        return termId;
    }

    public void setTermId(int termId) {
        this.termId = termId;
    }

    public String getTermTitle() {
        return termTitle;
    }

    public void setTermTitle(String termTitle) {
        this.termTitle = termTitle;
    }

    public String getTermStart() {
        return termStart;
    }

    public void setTermStart(String termStart) {
        this.termStart = termStart;
    }

    public String getTermEnd() {
        return termEnd;
    }

    public void setTermEnd(String termEnd) {
        this.termEnd = termEnd;
    }
}
```

TermAdapter where the object is accessed.

```
public class TermAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TermAdapter.TermViewHolder> {

    class TermViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView termItemView;


        private TermViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            termItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.termTextView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    final TermEntity current = mTerms.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TermDetailsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("termTitle", current.getTermTitle());
                    intent.putExtra("startTerm", current.getTermStart());
                    intent.putExtra("endTerm", current.getTermEnd());
                    intent.putExtra("termId", current.getTermId());
                    intent.putExtra("position",position);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

From the Activity where the intent is picked up

```
        if(getIntent().getStringExtra("termTitle")!=null) {
            String start = getIntent().getStringExtra("termStart");
            nameView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("termTitle"));
            startView.setText(start);
            endView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("termEnd"));
        }
```

It does create an object and inserts into the database, but later when I use the getter function for the start and end strings to populate a textView, they show up as null. The program doesn't error, the fields just appear blank.

I should add my theory is based on running debug w/breakpoints on the last two lines of the first code block. On this line:
TermEntity termEntity= new TermEntity(1,termTitle, strDateOne, strDateTwo);
my IDE showed the values for strDateOne and strDateTwo as strings.
When it ran the next line however, instead of being surrounded by single quotes like 'Term 1', they did not have quotes.

Comment: add your TermEntity class and how you are getting it

Comment: Entity added.  Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use wrong intent bundle names. "startTerm", "termStart" and for end so on

To avoid this use constant string `INTENT_CONST` in sending activity and use it from a recieving activity like `intent.getExtras(SendingActivity.INTENT_CONST, value);`

Comment: I didn't realize that the top line: @Entity(tableName="term_table") had not copied into my question.  It has been there the whole time...

Comment: strange didn't saw it where you get your value? add getter function then

Comment: I've added a few more blocks of code from the project.  Thanks again for looking at it.

Comment: I don't see your @Query function where you are getting TermEntity back from DB

Comment: Good point.  I've added the TermViewModel which is calling the functions, then the Adapter is accessing the textView attached there to the ViewHolder.
I do know that it's getting the object back from the database, because the termTitle is populating as it should.

Comment: I'm confused. Where exactly you lose a data. When you create  recycler it's ok but when you get in on click it wrong?

Comment: It is confusing!  Yes, it seems to be fine when the recycler is created.  The information is present (in some form), until the receiving activity (the last code block), when I try to put the startDate and endDate extras into textViews (startView and endView respectively).  At that point the data is null, even though the textView (nameView) is receiving it's data just fine.

Comment: You chose so confusing question name. It's all about you intent i'm update a answer

Comment: Sorry about the question: I thought the problem was going to be something else!  Thank you.  Your solution fixed the problem. I'd upvote you, but I apparently don't have the reputation to do that yet.